# How to use a server for android app?

Tags: android, mysql, wamp

I am new to Android. I am developing an application which requires to connect with MySQL to fetch some data. Currently on my pc I am using WAMP server to test my app.
But I know that there are some server hosting websites that let us put our data on their severs. But I don't know whether it is possible with android app or not. And also I don't know if they provide MySQL database. Can anyone guide me with this and also the working of these hosting websites?

Answer (score 2):

You can pull data from servers by using HTTPGet method. Also you can post your applications data to server database by using HTTPPost method. You have to write some php files on server in order to make communication between your application and server.

On the server side, in your php files you have to poll your needed information from database for example by querying and then you have to parse them as JSON data. Then from your application, you can create some service that send HTTPGet request to url you give and poll JSON data from server. Afterwards is  an easy parsing job.